# MapReduce count and find average

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I want to develop a program in MapReduce which get cust_key and balance values from a .tbl file.I have concatenate the 2 values into string and then send it to the Reducer, so i will count the cust_key and find the average balance per segment.That's why i have added the segment as key.

I want to split the string and get the 2 values sepatated in order to count the cust keys and sum the balance to find the average.But splitted array[0] gives me the whole string, not the first value of the string.Also splitted array[1] throws ArrayoutofBounds exception.I hope it's clear.

The code is below

```
public class MapReduceTest {

        public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

         private Text segment = new Text();

         private Text word = new Text();

         private float balance = 0;


         public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           String[] line = value.toString().split("\\|");

           balance = Float.parseFloat(line[5]);

           String cust_key = line[1];

           int nation = Integer.parseInt(line[3]);

           if((balance > 8000) && ( nation < 15) && (nation > 1)){ 

             segment.set(line[6]);

             //word.set(cust_key+","+balance);

             word.set(cust_key+","+balance);

             context.write(segment,word);
           }
         }

       }

    public static class AvgReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {


         Text val = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

         String cust_key = "";
         float avg,sum = 0;
         int count = 0;
            for(Text v : values){
                 String[] a = v.toString().trim().split(",");

                 cust_key +=a[0];

            }

            val.set(cust_count);

            context.write(key, val);

     }

   }
```

Input data

```
8794|Customer#000008794|6dnUgJZGX73Kx1idr6|18|28-434-484-9934|7779.30|HOUSEHOLD|deposits detect furiously even requests. furiously ironic packages are slyly into th
8795|Customer#000008795|oA1cLUtWOAIFz5Douypbq1jHv glSE|9|19-829-732-8102|9794.80|BUILDING|totes. blithely unusual theodolites integrate carefully ironic foxes. unusual excuses cajole carefully carefully fi
8796|Customer#000008796|CzCzpV7SDojXUzi4165j,xYJuRv wZzn grYsyZ|24|34-307-411-6825|4323.03|AUTOMOBILE|s. pending, bold accounts above the sometimes express accounts 
8797|Customer#000008797|TOWDryHNNqp8bvgMW6 FAhRoLyG1ldu2bHcJCM6|2|12-517-522-5820|219.78|FURNITURE|ly bold pinto beans can nod blithely quickly regular requests. fluffily even deposits ru
8798|Customer#000008798|bIegyozQ5kzprN|15|25-472-647-6270|6832.96|AUTOMOBILE|es-- silent instructions nag blithely
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at MapReduceTest$AvgReducer.reduce(MapReduceTest.java:69)
        at MapReduceTest$AvgReducer.reduce(MapReduceTest.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
17/04/12 18:40:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local806960399_0001 running in uber mode : false
17/04/12 18:40:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/04/12 18:40:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local806960399_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
17/04/12 18:40:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 35
```

Update

Reducer

```
    public static class AvgReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AvgReducer.class.getName());

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            float sumBalance=0,avgBalance = 0;

            int cust_count = 1;

            for(Text v : values){
               String[] a = v.toString().trim().split(",");

               //c2 += " i "+i+" "+a[0]+"\n";

               sumBalance +=Float.parseFloat(a[a.length-1]);

               cust_count++;
            }

            avgBalance = sumBalance / cust_count;


            context.write(key,new Text(avgBalance+" "+cust_count));

     }

   }
```

StackTrace

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8991.715 289"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try printing out the `value`? It probably doesn't have enough `|` to be split in a 7 element array.

Comment: The question is too broad. Where is the [mcve]. If you have spend hours on this, can you spend a few minutes to add more information ? What is the problem, what input/output ... And of course, don't use short url to post anything, I will not click on those links, mainly because the firewall here will block those...

Comment: Can you provide the sample input data.

Comment: Have you considered using Hive, Pig, or Spark for this?

Comment: I don't know i should?

Comment: Your data isn't that complex, but 1) Provide the stacktrace here. 2) if you are getting `cust_key +=a[0]` as out of bounds, have you tried just printing `v`? What is it?

Comment: When i print v, it prints the whole string, a[0] prints only the customer key, a[1] gives the exception.

Comment: Does using `Pattern.quote("|")` make any difference? `value.toString().split(Pattern.quote("|"));`

Comment: @DanW The error is in the reducer on `split(",")`

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Have you shown all the data here, or only a sample?

Comment: It's a sample, it's too big.

Comment: I would recommend you to run following command `hdfs dfs -cat /path/on/hdfs/* | awk -F'|' '{print NF}' | sort -u`.

Answer (score 2):

Pig runs MapReduce (if configured that way). It's also much cleaner than mucking around with MapReduce, and comes installed on the major Hadoop distributions.

```
A = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (f1:int,customer_key:chararray,f3:chararray,nation:int,f5:chararray,balance:float,segment:chararray,f7:chararray);
filtered = FILTER A BY balance > 8000 AND (nation > 1 AND nation < 15);
X = FOREACH filtered generate segment,customer_key,balance;
```

And output

```
\d X
(BUILDING,Customer#000008795,9794.8)
```

Not sure you really want the average here, there is only one element, but you'll need to `GROUP BY` on the `segment` and `customer_key`, then you can easily use [`AVG` function](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/func.html#avg).

---

If you are more familiar with SQL, then Hive may also be a more straight-forward approach.

(Also runs via MapReduce unless configured otherwise)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (
    f1 INT,
    customer_key STRING, 
    f3 STRING, 
    nation INT,
    f5 STRING,
    balance FLOAT,
    f8 STRING
) ROW FORMAT DELIMETED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LOCATION 'hdfs://path/test.txt';
```

Then, it'd be something like this

```
SELECT segment, customer_key, AVG(balance)
FROM records
WHERE balance > 8000 AND nation > 1 AND nation < 15
GROUP BY segment, customer_key;
```

---

I'd go into the Apache Spark example, but Spark SQL would essentially be that Hive query.

Comment: I appreciate all the help but i should implement it only with MapReduce.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you'd want to write 50+ lines of code that you could do in 10 or less.

Comment: It's a small program for my project.The professor wants to develop it on MapReduce to learn better :)

Comment: ok man, i will check for null values before sending the Text to the reducer.

Comment: Or if there is no input at all... If you get null, then you'd see `NullPointerException`, not out of bounds. Also, you didn't mention how you are running this job, but I assume `hadoop jar`

Comment: yes, hadoop jar.So i will check if null and empty balance then balance = 0.

Comment: Your mapper should work fine for the values that you've provided

Comment: Your right even if check for null values i should get nullpointerexception

Comment: i tried a[a.length-1] and it works, but how i will find the number of elements

Comment: Finally, using a[0] i get all the cust keys, but how to find the number of elements :)

Comment: Isn't that a simple counter? `int count = 0; for (...) { count++; } print(count);` ?

Comment: Yes but when i output from the Reducer i get exception   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8991.715 i 289"  because of context.write(key, avgBalance+" i "+i). At the end i want to print the key, avg balance and number of customers. Thank you

Comment: You can test your code independently of Hadoop, you know? I would recommend that.

Comment: How? i tried to put the hadoop paths but it doesn't work

Comment: No, no. I said **outside of** hadoop. Meaning, run the mapper, but replace `context.write` with `System.out.println` and then copy that output and run it directly through the reducer code. It's much easier with Python (or any other quick scripting language). http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: ok man, i should run the hadoop jar and it will output the result in cmd?

Comment: No.... When I said "test independently of hadoop", why do you think you need `hadoop jar`?

Comment: because i am new with mapreduce programs, so i will just run it, but for input ?

Comment: All I'm trying to say is that you should **always** test a representative, small sample dataset without Hadoop before writing it in MapReduce so you can fix any logical errors.

Comment: no offence :) It will work with mapper and reducer? because i must specify input and output, any tutorial?

Comment: Then give different input and output! Don't run `hadoop jar`. Create a completely separate project, and rewrite the code without Hadoop classes, just pure Java. It doesn't require a tutorial

Comment: I tried splitting string in java and it works fine.I solved that, i am facing another issue now, when i try to display the output of the reducer, it throws exception.Check the updated

Comment: The reducer isn't just one step. Multiple reducers get ran after one another. `avgBalance+" "+cust_count` seems to be producing `8991.715 289`, which you can't parse as a float

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to try this in Java MapReduce, try standardizing your inputs and catch errors fast.

Return to discard problematic records

```
     public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       float balance = 0.0;
       String custKey = "";
       String segment = "";
       int nation = 0;

       String[] line = value.toString().split("\\|");
       if (line.length < 7) { 
           System.err.println("map: Not enough records");
           return;
       }
       cust_key = line[1];
       try {
           nation = Integer.parseInt(line[3]);
           balance = Float.parseFloat(line[5]);
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return;
       }

       if(balance > 8000 && (nation < 15 && nation > 1)){ 
         segment.set(line[6]);
         word.set(cust_key + "\t" + balance);
         context.write(segment,word);
       }
  }
```

Then, the reducer should ideally generate the same format if you are trying to write similar output records

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        float sumBalance=0
        int count = 0;

        for(Text v : values){
           String[] a = v.toString().trim().split("\t");
           if (a.length < 2) {
               System.err.println("reduce: Not enough records");
               continue;
           }

           sumBalance += Float.parseFloat(a[1]);
           count++;
        }

        float avgBalance = count <= 1 ? sumBalance : sumBalance / count;

        context.write(key,new Text(avgBalance + "\t" + count));

 }
```

(code untested)